# Run jQuery on click function but not on a child

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom-events, jquery-events

I have a `click` event handler on a jQuery variable `rangeCont`. This is a `<div>` with a few children. When a user clicks on it, I want the event handler to work but not for one of the children it contains which has a class of "thumb".

When I click on the thumb, in the console `e.target` is `span.thumb`. Does the `:not` condition not work in the selector or am I doing something wrong?

```js
const rangeCont = $('<div class="range-slider"></div>'),
  track = $('<span class="track">track</span>');
progressTrack = $('<span class="progress-track">progress</span>'),
  thumbHigh = $('<span class="thumb">thumb</span>');

rangeCont.append(track);
progressTrack.append(thumbHigh);
rangeCont.append(progressTrack);
$('body').append(rangeCont);

rangeCont.on('click', ':not(.thumb)', function(e) {
  console.log(e.target);
});
```

```css
span {
  margin: 0 1em;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.range-slider {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  padding: 1em 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Edit: Quotes don't make a difference on `:not`.
I've noticed `e.target` is `span.thumb` but `e.currentTarget` is `span.progress-track` which is underneath the thumb if that's important.

Comment: It's working just fine for me.

Comment: how did you define `rangeCont` here?

Comment: Add a `""` around .thumb in not selector to be ```rangeCont.on('click', ':not(".thumb")', function(e){```

Comment: Quotes are not necessary. See [`:not()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not)

Comment: Edit my edit, so it matches your code!

Comment: Your code works fine in chrome, what's your browser?

Comment: I'm using Chrome as well

Comment: @connexo Thanks. I'll keep it in mind. I did wanted to share as little code as possible.

Comment: The way your HTML is generated is important. As it turns out, `thumbHigh` is a child of `progressTrack` and the answers below about preventing event propagation are indeed relevant.

Comment: The js code to generate the HTML does *not* generate the HTML you've provided.  This clarifies where you've stated in comments *"Since .thumb is a child of .progress-track"* - it's clearly NOT a child in the generated HTML.

Comment: On option is to add an event directly to `.thumb` itself that does nothing except stop propagation.  Then it won't propagate to the parent(s).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can directly check the e.target of your event and add a condition that ensure that the click is on the right target.

The event will still be raised, but you can cancel it without touching the propagation.

```
$('#rangeCont').on('click', function(e) {
    if ($(e.target).is('.thumb'))
        return;

    console.log(e.target);
});
```

Comment: This seems to be the best option so far. Its working but I'd still like to know why `:not()` isn't working.

Comment: @VeeK The event handler is bound to `.progress-track`. Since `.thumb` is a child of `.progress-track`, the event [bubbles up](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#Bubbling_and_capturing_explained) from that element as well, even though the handler is bound to its parent. The target of the event is not necessarily the element to which the event is bound. See [target](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target) vs [currentTarget](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget).

Comment: So when I write `:not(.thumb)`, it will not execute the function but will still propagate the event to its parent `.progress-track` and then execute the function there?

Comment: @VeeK Yes, I believe that's what's going on. Clicking on `.thumb` bubbles a click event to `.progress-track` which triggers your event handler.

Answer (score -1):

Stop bubbling up event from child to parent using `stopPropagation`. Use below code

```
$(".range-container .thumb").on('click', function(e){
   event.stopPropagation();
});
```

For more information refer [this](https://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) link.

Comment: I would avoid this solution as much as possible. By stopping the propagation, you can possibly have an impact on others javascript on the page.